# pstool stopped working

Tags: psfrag

In some figures I create for my thesis I want to replace the labels and such using the same font and size as in the rest of the thesis. A couple of month ago I already used psfrag and pstool (with pdflatex). But now I cannot get it working. I did not changed any files (using a version control system, so I'm pretty sure).

The following mini example produces the same error as in my thesis:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pstool}

\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}     
\centering  
\psfragfig*{Inverses_Pendel} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the same directory are the files `Inverses_Pendel.eps` and `Inverses_Pendel.tex`.
`Inverses_Pendel.tex` contains the following content:

```
\psfrag{T}[cc][cc]{$Test$}
```

And here is the error:

> Package pstool Warning: Execution failed during process:   ps2pdf
>   "-dAutoFilterColorImages=false" "-dAutoFilterGrayImages=false" "-dColo
>   rImageFilter=/FlateEncode" "-dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode"
>   "-dPDFSETTINGS=/pre press" "Inverses_Pendel-pstool.ps"
>   "Inverses_Pendel.pdf" This warning occurred on input line 7.
>
> ! Missing $ inserted.  
>                   $ l.7 \end
>           {figure} ?  ! Emergency stop.  
>                   $ l.7 \end
>           {figure} End of file on the terminal!

It's such a generic error, I don't even know where to start searching.

I'm using MikTeX 2.9. I'm passing the `-shell-escape` option.

Comment: The "Missing $" error looks a bit if the underscore in your file name leds to errors. But this is perhaps only a side effect. If you get an error also when you remove the underscore you should put the `eps` and the `tex` somewhere for download so that other can makes tests.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - Removing the underscore fixed my problem with the "Missing $" error. Thank you for that! But now the generated pdf contains a red text message: "An error occured processing graphic './InversesPendel'" ... I will do a some research first, and update the question, if I dont get that error fixed.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - Solved my other problem too. It seems my MiKTeX installation was broken, ps2pdf didn't work. When you make your comment an answer I would accept it, because it solved my initial problem ("Missing $" error).

Comment: I had the exact same problem: first missing $ error, then, after removing underscores from the filename, the error processing graphic. I removed the whole TeX distribution from my machine (mac os x) and reinstalled the full MacTex-2014 package. After doing so, pstool worked again with a filename without underscores. Cocky as I am, I tried a filename with underscore again and well, that lead to the same errors as before. Including the problem that even files without underscore refused working. So same thing again: remove, reinstall and pay attention to not use underscores ever again!

Comment: has somebody a more clever idea than just not using underscores in filenames anymore? They worked perfectly fine until I last tried about 3 weeks ago..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Missing $" error looks a bit if the underscore in your file name leds to errors. But this is perhaps only a side effect. If you get an error also when you remove the underscore you should put the `eps` and the `tex` somewhere for download so that other can makes tests.